# Android WebView Cache/Cookie issue

Tags: android, webview

In the beginning, my WebView refreshed changes to the WebView and then suddendly it stopped refreshing / showing new, updated content which I pull from a website.
I am using the WebView inside a fragment like this:

```
public class newsfeedFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed,container,false);

        myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView webview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.loadUrl("https://website.com/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;

    }
}
```

I have tried some of the solutions in other posts but I couldn´t make it work. If somebody has a solution for this, I´d be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your `WebView` by calling below codes, it will remove all cookies of you webview

```
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```